# Making this contact form responsive with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript but in mid-level with HTML and CSS.

So here is the issue. I just registered a third party contact form service with Foxyform. They provided a code to paste in the page and upload it. It works fine in desktop views, however when one visits the contact page on different mobile or smaller devices it looks out of space and non-responsive. There is no option to edit it in @media screen within the theme.

Is it possible to make this contact form responsive?

Here are the codes:

HTML:

```
<a id="foxyform_embed_link_602624" href="http://www.foxyform.com/"></a>
```

Javascript:

```
(function(d, t) {
var g = d.createElement(t),
s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
g.src = "http://www.foxyform.com/js.php?id=602624&sec_hash=54f3ab77bfb&width=350px";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
}(document, "script"));
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to make your own css stylesheet and include it?

Comment: is it creating form using iframe(is your form  located in iframe), or it's just a form?

Comment: Sorry, they did not provide any css code

Comment: @sarhov it's just a form. If you need i can provide the whole code they provided.

Comment: yes, the snapshot from source code or the piece of its generated html will help us, to understand if we can control its preference with css

Comment: why are you including the same again in a comment if it's already in your original question? you may just want to edit your question instead to make it look correct...?

Comment: @webeno, sarhov asked me the full code, so i provided it :-)

Comment: @Supam just edit your original question, no reason for putting these into the comment only... it's just the way of things.

Comment: Sorry then... after all, as in the question just combining HTML and JS code is the full code

Comment: It really seems like you ought to first address this question to the providers of the form to see what capabilities they provide for responsive layout or an alternate form that works on smaller screens.  You may or may not find a work-around with help here, but you also may be missing the supported way to solve this problem if you don't contact the people who provide the form service and ask them.

Comment: I emailed them, still waiting for their honest reply..

Answer (score 1):

Your contactform provider includes an **iframe** in your page.

An **iframe** can not be styled by the website on which is it included as most browser handle it as an own webpage which is embedded in another webpage.

Comment: how do you know it's an iframe...?

Comment: I looked in the code the script which he includes loads. (http://www.foxyform.com/js.php?id=602624&sec_hash=54f3ab77bfb&width=350px) There is the line `i = d.createElement('IFRAME');` which basiclly means that the script creates an **iframe** element to show the form.

Comment: Oh that is really nice. Thanks. I don't have any clue on these. So is it possible to edit it for making it responsive?

Comment: ah, it makes sense now... @Supam nope, as explained... check out their documentation, maybe they're providing some directions for that...

Comment: it only convinces me to opt for another service...thanks @webeno and Reflic for clearing out my head

Comment: @Supam don't hesitate to vote up or accept the answer, as you see fit, of course...

Comment: ...i just did @Reflic ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix with CSS (not jquery/javascript sorry) ( for googleCalendar iframe ) but I used the same concept for foxyForms iframe.

via https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/make-google-calendar-iframe-responsive/

html

```
    <div class="responsiveCal">

      <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed? showTitle=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=2&amp;hl=nl&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=example.be_cpkbjcpttgb5q0%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23ffcf03&amp;ctz=Europe%2FBrussels" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
```

css

```
    .responsiveCal {

      position: relative; padding-bottom: 75%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;

    }

    .responsiveCal iframe {

      position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;

    }
```

It allowed me to place a row within the container as well to use bootstraps responsive classes. Hope this is right, I'm still a beginner please feel free to correct any mistakes I made..